# Installing Windows ME on a PC with a damaged floppy

Tags: windows, format

I have a huge problem, I want to install Windows ME on an old PC, but I really dont know how.

I have installed XP a million times, but WinMe is different, can you help me install WinMe without a floppy?

Comment: Is there a reason why you prefer ME over XP? As I understand it they require roughly the same hardware, but ME is seriously buggy...

Comment: because as i have installed the XP in it, the system unit hangs up in post, but if i transfer the HDD into another pc, it will boot.. plus the system unit is made for Win98 and WinME,

Comment: "I have a huge problem, I want to install Windows ME"

Comment: Seriously though, if the computer hangs during POST, it couldn't possibly be OS-related.